# java, issue calling method from another class

Tags: java, class, for-loop, methods, call

So, i've been working on a program to graph and calculate tax rates of arbitrary values for a project i'm working on, however i've hit a snag, I cannot seem to get a function to operate properly

```
public void name3()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < incomeSet.length; i++)
    {
        double totalTaxes = 0.0;
        double income = incomeSet[i];
        TaxCalculator tx1 = new TaxCalculator();
        totalTaxes = tx1.totalTaxes(incomeSet[i]);

    }
}
```

I get the error:
the method totalTaxes(int) is undefined for the type taxCalculator

this occurs on tx1.totalTaxes(

I am calling TaxCalculator from another class

Not sure if the error is here or in the other class, I will post the code for that class if needed, but due to this being an assignment I'd like to avoid that if possible

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculator 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int income;

        System.out.println("Please enter gross income:");
        income = keyboardInput.nextInt();

        ...

        while (income >= 0) 
        {

            ...

            break;
        }

        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the method definition from `TaxCalculator`?

Comment: Well apparently there's no `totaltaxes(int)` method in `TaxCalculator`... what makes you think there is such a method?

Comment: @JonSkeet you mean double?

Comment: this code is probably fine. no way to answer your question without you posting the other class

Comment: There is no method named `totalTaxes` in your `TaxCalculator's` code.

Comment: @DavidBrossard: No, I mean `int`, given the error message. Note that `incomeSet[i]` is being passed in, not `income` - so if `incomeSet` is an `int[]`, it's entirely consistent.

Comment: And now that we can see `TaxCalculator`, the *only* method in it is a `main` method, so it's not clear what you expected to be called...

Comment: @JonSkeet Basically, I am wanting to apply the method taxCalculator to the values of tx1, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @MarianneVossSiljan: There's no such method as `taxCalculator`. There's a *class* called `TaxCalculator`, but that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh yeah well spotted. This means though the code doesn't match the error msg.

Comment: @DavidBrossard: The only way it doesn't is that the type is called `TaxCalculator` not `taxCalculator`.

Comment: What on earth are you doing with the question? How many "thank you" questions have you seen here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

You could make the method:

```
public double totalTaxes(double incomeSet)
```

in your `TaxCalculator` class